# Localhost:3000 displaying a blank screen when using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Chrome Version 75.0.3770.142, macOS Mojave I already disabled adblockers and checked the console, and addressed the errors there but localhost:3000 is still displaying a blank page. I was following the official Facebook React Tutorial (https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) and finished the [Inspecting Starter Code Section](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#inspecting-the-starter-code) when I decided to run npm start in my directory to see the result.

Comment: when you run "npm start" what shows up?

Comment: Check your terminal and see if you have any error message

Comment: Terminal shows no error messages.